# MediaElementJs Firefox flash fallback "this.pluginApi.pauseMedia is not a function"

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have a problem in my implementation of `mediaelementjs`. I need to have a list of links which will change the video source. The problem is that the second time I click hover the link, every time I click on the play button the debbugger say me "this.pluginApi.pauseMedia is not a function". This happen in Firefox with flash fallback.
This is my code to change video:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var player = null;
var videoCounter = 0;
var videoSubsLang = 'es';


function loadVideo(videoSource){
    if(player != null){
        //player.pause();
    }

    player = null;

    if(typeof(videoSource)==='undefined') videoSource = '';

    var videoURL = 'video.mp4';

    $("#mep_"+videoCounter).remove();

    var htmlVideo = '<video width="512" height="384" src="'+videoURL+'" id="player" poster="video.jpg" controls="controls" preload="auto">';
    htmlVideo += '<track kind="subtitles" src="video_en.srt" srclang="en" />';
    htmlVideo += '<object width="512" height="384" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="js/player_mejs/flashmediaelement.swf">';
    htmlVideo += '<param name="movie" value="js/player_mejs/flashmediaelement.swf" />';
    htmlVideo += '<param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file='+videoURL+'" />';
    htmlVideo += '</object>';
    htmlVideo += '</video>';

    $('#tutsVideoHolder').append(htmlVideo);


    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player', {startLanguage: videoSubsLang, features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','fullscreen'], translationSelector: false,
        success: function (mediaElement) { 
            alert('success');
            // add event listener
           mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
                 alert('pause');
            }, true);

           mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
                 alert('pause');   
            }, true);

        }
    });
    videoCounter++;

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player', {startLanguage: 'en', features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','fullscreen'], translationSelector: false});

});

</script>
```

my html is this:

```
<div id="tutsVideoHolder" class="tuts_video_holder left">    
    <video width="512" height="384" id="player" poster="poster.jpg" controls="controls">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>

        <track kind="subtitles" src="video_subs.vtt" srclang="en" />

        <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="js/player_mejs/flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="js/player_mejs/flashmediaelement.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=video.mp4" />

            <img src="poster.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities" />
        </object>
    </video>        
</div>
```

please Help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are disabling the video element or its parent element, so when you try to set the `src` the `mediaplayerjs` element is disabled. I recommend that instead of hiding or showing the video to instead change the z-index of the video element or its parent.